# NET 8 Class Library native dll not valid

Tags: c#, dll, native, .net-8.0

I'm trying to reference a native dll created with .NET 8.
I have created a NET 8 Class Library Project and added the PublishAot Attribute to the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Then I added a simple class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestNativeLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1() { }

        [UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Get_Text")]
        public static void GetText()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey du");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have compiled it:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release
```

Compilation runs without failure.
After the compilation there are 4 files in the native folder:

- TestNativeLib.dll
- TestNativeLib.exp
- TestNativeLib.lib
- TestNativeLib.pdb

I tried to reference the TestNativeLib.dll but I get the error that this file is not a valid Assembly or COM Component.

Compilation with following command results to the same result:

```
dotnet publish  /p:NativeLib=Static --use-current-runtime
```

Also tried Tblimp.exe to test the library with following output:

TlbImp : error TI1002 : The input file 'C:...\TestNativeLib\bin\Release\net8.0\win-x64\native\TestNativeLib.dll' is not a valid type library.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the reference to the original `TestNativeLib.dll`? Because while `PublishAot ` produces native code, it's not a standalone native DLL consumable by unmanaged applications. It's still managed code with optimizations for ahead-of-time compilation

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "original". I have tried to add a reference to the native output file in C:...\TestNativeLib\bin\Release\net8.0\win-x64\native\TestNativeLib.dll.

Comment: Well, If you're simply trying to use the DLL from another .NET application, reference it directly as a .NET assembly (not a type library)

Comment: Original means the `native DLL`

Comment: The goal is to make it available to none .NET Core or .NET Framework Applications.

Comment: Native AoT isn't designed to make .NET code callable from non-.NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working.

First I had to copy the output of the native compilation into the debug output folder of the consuming application, then I simple had to use the `DllImport` Attribute just like that:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestNativeConsumer
{
    internal class Program
    {

        [DllImport("TestLib.dll", EntryPoint = "Get_Text")]
        private static extern void GetText();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                GetText();
            }
            catch (DllNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"DLL not found: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need reference the DLL anywhere else.
I also compiled the `TestNativeConsumer` application in `x64` because of the runtime settings of the exported DLL.